# Matching div height to combined height of other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, height, settimeout

I'm trying to match the height of background div to the combined height of divs in front. I used simple jQuery height function and it kind of worked:

```
var originalHeight = $("#topbg").height() + $("#menurowbg").height() + $("#headerbg").height() + $("#contentareabg").height() + $("#footerbg").height();
$("#wrapper").height(originalHeight);
```

The problem is, the height needs to change dynamically if one of those divs is resized to keep matching. I tried to put the setTimeout function, but failed. I'm obviously missing something but can't figure it out. Please help this jQuery rookie. Here's my current code:

```
var originalHeight = $("#topbg").height() + $("#menurowbg").height() + $("#headerbg").height() + $("#contentareabg").height() + $("#footerbg").height();

setTimeout function checkHeight() {
if(originalHeight < ($("#topbg").height() + $("#menurowbg").height() + $("#headerbg").height() + $("#contentareabg").height() + $("#footerbg").height())) 
{
originalHeight = $("#topbg").height() + $("#menurowbg").height() + $("#headerbg").height() + $ ("#contentareabg").height() + $("#footerbg").height();
}
}, 500);

$("#wrapper").height(originalHeight);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three scenarios:

1) Use `setInterval()` rather than `setTimeout()` to execute code ever X amount of milliseconds:

```
setInterval(function() {
    setContainerSize();
}, 1000);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XWmdL/3/

2) The containing div is the parent of the divs being resized.  In that case, You don't have to add all the heights together and reset the container's height.  You can just set the container's width and height attributes to `auto`:

```
#container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XWmdL/1/

3) If your child divs are being resized when the window size changes, you need to use the `$(window).resize()` event.  Change the viewing window size in the following example and you'll see the red background size change as the yellow div changes.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XWmdL/2/

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but for reasons that will take too long to explain, it is NOT a container div. It is an absolutely positioned div behind rest of the elements, so I can't use this.

Comment: Hmm, are the "inside" divs being resized when the window size changes? Or some other way?

Comment: I added to my answer.

Comment: yes, those divs can be resized, when for example a textarea inside one of them is resized vertically and its container div is resized with it. I saw your jsfiddle update but it does not work. I just need a way to correctly implement the setTimeout function to check for height regularly. My original jQuery worked, but not for resize.

Comment: In that case I think you want setInterval() rather than setTimeout(). See 1) in my answer. Sorry, I didn't understand exactly what you wanted. :p

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. I am upvoting you, but it works only partially and not exactly for what I wanted. I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XWmdL/5/ the main thing is, resizing the textarea is not detected. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @George, if you set #resiable height to a percentage it will automatically update. Alternatively, you can increase #resiable's height in the .click() function: http://jsfiddle.net/XWmdL/6/

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I'm not trying to change the height of the #resizable when the height of parent is changed. It's the other way around - I'm trying to change the background height when #resizable is resized with a mouse click-and-drag.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I'm actually not sure how to do that. You can, however, use a form in place of the parent div. Form's will automatically expand as their components expand: http://jsfiddle.net/XWmdL/7/

Answer (score 0):

First the condition is wrong

```
 setTimeout function checkHeight() {
if(originalHeight < (jQuery("#topbg").height() + jQuery("#menurowbg").height() +      jQuery("#headerbg").height() + jQuery("#contentareabg").height() + jQuery("#footerbg").height())) {

originalHeight = jQuery("#topbg").height() + jQuery("#menurowbg").height() + jQuery("#headerbg").height() + jQuery("#contentareabg").height()+jQuery("#footerbg").height();

jQuery("#wrapper").height(originalHeight);

}, 500);
```

Comment: how does your answer help? I already knew it was wrong as mentioned in my original post. I'm looking for help, not criticism.